# What is the difference between GZIPOutputStream and DeflaterOutputStream?

Tags: java, gzipoutputstream

`GZIPOutputStream` is just a subclass of `DeflaterOutputStream` but both can be instantiated. When do I use one over the other? Is the compression the same?

Comment: In addition to the answers, GZIP is interesting as the output will be compatible with many tools without having to jump hoops, such as zcat, zgrep, and tools than can open gz archives.

Answer (score 19):

The differences between [DeflaterOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html), [ZIPOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html), and [GZIPOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) reflect the difference between their historic compression predecessors:

- [deflate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)
- [zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_file_format)
- [gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)

respectively. Deflate can be considered the reference implementation of the compression algorith, while ZIP and GZIP are 'extensions' to it. Both the latter support the concept of 'archives', which is much more evident in the Java API for ZipOutputStream.

If you are simply trying to compress a data stream I would recommend using the DeflaterOutputStream, but if you are creating an archive you should probably look at ZipOutputStream instead.

Answer (score 5):

DeflaterOutputStream implements the raw deflate compression method.  GZIPOutputStream adds additional logic required for GZIP: CRC-32 checking, the GZIP magic number, GZIP header, trailer, etc.  See the source for [GZIPOutputStream.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.java.html) and [DeflaterOutputStream.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.java.html).

Comment: In orginal response link does not work: [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html)

Comment: @Stephan web archive ;) [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://web.archive.org/web/20180411212931/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html)

Comment: @Puddle I didn't notice g051051 has updated the links. I remove my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the specific compression format used. From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) for DeflaterOutputStream:

```
public class DeflaterOutputStream
extends FilterOutputStream

This class implements an output stream filter for compressing data in the "deflate" compression format. It is also used as the basis for other types of compression filters, such as GZIPOutputStream.
```

[GZIPOutputStream says](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html):

```
public class GZIPOutputStream
extends DeflaterOutputStream

This class implements a stream filter for writing compressed data in the GZIP file format.
```

The GZIP stream extends the Deflate implementation with additional details specific to the GZIP file format.